# your_pic.set(latest_photo) AttributeError: 'Picture' object has no attribute 'set'

Tags: python, guizero

I can't work out how to give the 'Picture' object a attribute 'set' in this code so my code for your_pic.set(lastest_photo) is not working properly.  The 3rd line from the bottom defines the Picture, so I'm not sure what I'm missing.  Could someone please help.

```
from picamera import PiCamera
from gpiozero import Button
from time import gmtime, strftime
from overlay_functions import *
from guizero import App, PushButton, Text, Picture

def next_overlay():
    global overlay
    overlay = next(all_overlays)
    preview_overlay(camera, overlay)

def take_picture():
    global output
    output = strftime("/home/pi/allseeingpi/image-%d-%m %H:%M.png", gmtime())
    camera.capture(output)
    camera.stop_preview()
    remove_overlays(camera)
    output_overlay(output, overlay)

    size = 400, 400
    gif_img = Image.open(output)
    gif_img.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    gif_img.save(latest_photo, 'gif')

    your_pic.set(latest_photo)

def new_picture():
    camera.start_preview(alpha=128)
    preview_overlay(camera, overlay)

next_overlay_btn = Button(23)
next_overlay_btn.when_pressed = next_overlay
take_pic_btn = Button(25)
take_pic_btn.when_pressed = take_picture

camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (800, 480)
camera.hflip = True

camera.start_preview()

output = ""
latest_photo = '/home/pi/allseeingpi/latest.gif'  

app = App("The All-Seeing Pi", 800, 480)
message = Text(app, "I spotted you!")
your_pic = Picture(app, latest_photo)
new_pic = PushButton(app, new_picture, text="New picture")
app.display()
```

Comment: Have you tried `your_pic = Picture(app, image=latest_photo)`?

Comment: Thank you. Will try

Comment: No luck, that didn't work.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Do you get any error messages? I've tried the lines from `app = ...` to `your_pic = ...` with an `app.display()` afterwards and it works just fine?

Comment: Yes it keeps saying    your_pic.set(latest_photo) attributeerror-picture-object-has-no-attribute-set
I’ve tried tens of different variables over hours/days. Run it through python reader and it says no error but when I hit run on my raspberry pi touchscreen it errors.

Comment: Then I'm out of my depth, sorry! Hope you find a solution.